# How to map objects into ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I have some data in the format of

```
data : {
  full_name: 'John Doe',
  date_of_birth: '01-01-1990'
}
```

I want to render it in a table format which would sort of look like

```
Full Name : John Doe
Date Of Birth: 01-01-1990
```

If it was an array, I could just do something like

```
data.map((item) => <h1>item</h1>
```

but I also need the to print the key.

How do I achieve something like this in a single loop like function? I could have used map in case of an array, but I also need to render the key part of the object.

***NOTE: Data object cannot be changed.***

Comment: Maybe something like `<td>{data.full_name}</td>`?

Comment: This might be helpful for you https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

Comment: @evolutionxbox this was just an example so i put less data, there is a lot of data in the actual object so i need something like map instead AND i also need to render the keys.

Comment: You can use for to loop and have access to the key and value```for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}``` inside this loop you can parse your key to replace _ with space and Capitalize First Character after space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the entries array, like this:

```js
Object.entries(data).map((entry, index) => (
    <div key={index}>{entry[0]}: {entry[1]}</div>
));
```

the `Object.entries` function creates an array of `[key, value]` arrays from the entries of the function.

Also, you may use a function that will convert keys from `snake_case` to readable format. Here is a one-line function that does this conversion:

```js
   const snakeToText = (str) => str.split('_').map((word) => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)).join(' ');
```

Answer (score 3):

Let say you have an object

```
const obj = {
  data: {
    full_name: "John Doe",
    date_of_birth: "01-01-1990"
  }
};
```

then you can use either of the following ways:

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**1)** Using [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
<div>
  {Object.keys(obj.data).map((key) => {
    return (
      <div> {key} - {obj.data[key]} </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

**2)** Using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
<div>
  {Object.entries(obj.data).map(([key, value]) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {key} - {value}
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
```

**EDITED:** If you want to convert `my_name` to `My Name` then you can create a utility function. You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```
function convertString(str) {
  return str
    .split("_")
    .map((str) => str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1))
    .join(" ");
}
```

and call this function as:

```
<div>
  {key.includes("_") ? convertString(key) : key} - {obj.data[key]}
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect. So how do i convert snake case to a normal string? Couldn't find much resources online.

Comment: Can you tell me an example? Then only I can help you better

Comment: Do you want `date_of_birth` to `Date Of Birth` ?

Comment: Yeah i wanna convert it like that.

Comment: You also want to capitalise the first character also?

Comment: @user16516348 I've updated the answer as well as code sandbox example. Have a look

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your data in `Object.entries` or `Object.values`.

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Example :

**Object.entries()**

```
   const object1 = {
     a: 'somestring',
     b: 42
   };
        
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object1)) {
       console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
    }
    
    // expected output:
    // "a: somestring"
    // "b: 42"
```

**Object.values()**

```
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};

console.log(Object.values(object1));
// expected output: Array ["somestring", 42, false]
```

```js
const data = {
  full_name: 'John Doe',
  date_of_birth: '01-01-1990'
};

const values = Object.entries(data);

console.log(values)

values.map(entry => console.log(entry[0] + " " + entry[1]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this like ,

```
let data = {
  full_name: 'John Doe',
  date_of_birth: '01-01-1990'
}
Object.keys(data).map((eachKey)=>{
return `${eachKey} : ${data[eachKey]}`
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const data = {
  full_name: "John Doe",
  date_of_birth: "01-01-1990"
};
export default function App() {
  const renderableData = () =>
    Object.keys(data).map((k) => {
      const label = k
        .replaceAll("_", " ")
        .split(" ")
        .map((i) => i[0].toUpperCase() + i.slice(1))
        .join(" ");

      return (
        <div>
          <div style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>{label}: &nbsp;</div>
          <div style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>{data[k]}</div>
        </div>
      );
    });

  return <div>{renderableData()}</div>;
}
```

example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-hill-hfvl5?file=/src/App.tsx:0-560